# Passing list to WHERE IN clause with JPQL causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, illegalargumentexception

I found today a (strange) issue while I was attempting to fetch objects from database by their ids using Hibernate and JPQL.

The method I call is:

```
List<User> userList = userDao.findUsersByIds(ids);
```

In details:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
(...)
       @Query("SELECT u FROM User u " +
                "WHERE u.id IN :ids")
        List<User> findUsersByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
}
```

I'm running out of ideas what the root cause ot this problem might be, since the list that's being passed is of type `List<Long>`. 
It causes following stacktrace, though:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [37] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validateCollectionValuedParameterBinding(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterListBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterListBindingImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterListBindingImpl.setBindValues(QueryParameterListBindingImpl.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameterList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:568) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:490) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Query Method if you are using spring):

```
List<User> findAllByIdIn(List<Long> id);
```

Or JPQL:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id IN ?1")
List<User> findUsersByIds(List<Long> id);
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the example with Query Method. I actually want to know what's the problem with my approach, since it's the one I've been using across the project, and to me it looks good, but there's clearly something wrong in this particular case.

Comment: Can you update your answer and add your entire class (repository)?

Comment: Your "userDao" class.

Comment: @Christiano Bombazar I updated my question to provide more details on UserDao

Comment: Your property id is Long type?

Comment: Check your list of type long, probably there is a null value in the middle.

Comment: id is of type Long, yes

Comment: Parameter value element [37] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
it indicates a non-null value, so I'm not sure if the problem is with nulls.
(see stacktrace I provided)